# Cannot change the scrolling text in MD_Parlola

Tags: arduino, display, esp32, arduino-c++, arduino-esp32

I am trying to display text, got from a webserver, on a FC16_HW matrix display, using an esp32. To simpify things, I created a small demo that looks like this:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <MD_Parola.h>
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::FC16_HW
#define MAX_DEVICES 4
#define CS_PIN 5

MD_Parola Display = MD_Parola(HARDWARE_TYPE, CS_PIN, MAX_DEVICES);
#define  BUF_SIZE  75
char one[BUF_SIZE] = {"hi"};

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Display.begin();
  Display.setIntensity(15);
  Display.displayClear();
  Display.displayScroll(one, PA_CENTER, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, 100);
}

void loop() 
{
  if(Display.displayAnimate()){
    char one[BUF_SIZE] = {"hello"};
    Display.displayReset();
  }
}
```

But for some reason, the text never changes to "hello" despite, setting the "one" char to it.

I tried differrent solutions for scrolling text, they all had the same problem. The `if(Display.displayAnimate())` definetly works, as I check it with a `Serial.println`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in `loop()` is:

```
void loop() 
{
  if(Display.displayAnimate()){
    char one[BUF_SIZE] = {"hello"};
    Display.displayReset();
  }
}
```

Just setting a variable called "one" to a string isn't going to display the string. You have to call `Display.displayScroll()` with the new value:

```
void loop() 
{
  if(Display.displayAnimate()){
    char one[BUF_SIZE] = {"hello"};
    Display.displayScroll(one, PA_CENTER, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, 100);
    Display.displayReset();
  }
}
```

I would suggest not using the same variable name as it's confusing and will hide the original variable. In fact there's no need to use a variable here at all unless you plan on modifying the string before you display it. So you could just write:

```
    Display.displayScroll("hello", PA_CENTER, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, 100);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do want to change the variable before scrolling, as I mentioned. I will try it now, and flag it if it works!